# My interval is not continuing after gets called second time

Tags: javascript, algorithm

[image]

**what i tried**

```
let intervalTimer = null;
function startTimer(callback, interval) {
    // Write the code that goes here
    intervalTimer = setInterval(() => {
        let obj = {number:0};
        if(callback(obj)) {

        } else {

        }
    },interval);
}
  
function callback(obj) {
obj.number++
console.log(obj.number);
return obj.number < 5;
}
```

this is my code so far - but i only manage to get 1. After that the eecution is not continuing.
How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Place the `let obj = {number:0};` outside the function closure, just like you did with the `let intervalTimer`. Because your adding zero to the callback, its gets incremented by 1,then it gets set back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

In the original, `obj` is being recreated each time the interval fires, hence it never advances.

This also returns the interval ID to the caller, allowing for multiple timers as per the requirement.

```js
function startTimer(callback, interval) {

    let obj = {number:0};

    const intervalTimer = setInterval(() => {
        if(!callback(obj)) {
            clearInterval(intervalTimer)
        }
    },interval)

    return intervalTimer
}

function callback(obj) {
    obj.number++
    console.log(obj.number)
    return obj.number < 5
}

const timer1 = startTimer(callback, 500)
const timer2 = startTimer(callback, 750)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following demonstrates the concurrent running of two timers. Each timer callback will log a value based on its `counter` variable. The first timer operates on an interval of 500ms, and the second, 1000ms.

Note the use of the logical OR operator (`||`):

- If the left-hand side of the operator evaluates to a truthy value (ie. we should continue), then the right-hand side (timer cancellation) is not evaluated.
- If the left-hand side of the operator evaluates to a falsy value, then the right-hand side (the cancellation) is evaluated, and the timer stops.

```js
const startTimer = (callback, interval = 1000) => {
    let counter = 1
    const tick = () => 
        (callback(counter++) || clearInterval(intervalId))
    const intervalId = setInterval(tick, interval)    
}

const countToTen = (counter) => {    
    console.log(counter)
    return counter < 10
}

const abcs = (counter) => {    
    // 65 is the start of the Latin Alphabet
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(64 + counter)) 
    return counter < 10
}

startTimer(countToTen, 500)
startTimer(abcs)
```